# COM objects load in MVC project when running on development server but NOT on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, com

I am referencing a COM API in my MVC 3 project, and when I run the project on VS development server I can interact with the API fine. However, when I run on IIS 7.5, the API only returns null objects. No error is thrown it simply returns null for everything.

I have no idea if there are security issues surrounding COM, I assumed any user on a machine could interact with a COM reference installed on the machine?

Comment: Is the com component registered on the server i.e. run cmd line `regsvr32 path\to\dll`>

Comment: what sort of COM objects are these ?

Comment: @Igor I have run regsvr32 on the dll and still same problem

Comment: @Yahia I have no idea what sort of COM object sorry I am completely unfamilliar with COM

Answer (score 0):

COM is prone to permissions/rights issues when used from a Service (IIS is just a special one)...  IF the COM objects do something "desktop-like" (i.e. Excel or similar) this is even more locked down since Vista...

You could try to circumvent that somehow but I wouldn't recommend that...

Comment: If I set in config to impersonate me with my usrname/password it works - is there any I can give IIS default user permissons to access the COM objects?

Comment: you could try to do that by adding the IIS user to the same groups etc. that you user is member of - although that is not recommended since it opens up an attack vector MS wanted to avoid by locking down IIS as much as possible